# Android App Crashes when I try to load it in the Emulator

Tags: android

I'm very new to Android programming and am having a rough start. I've created a general UI for a program and haven't changed any of the actual Java code. Whenever I try to load the app in the emulator just to see what it looks like, the app crashes. Does anyone have an idea as to why this would happen?

Also, other apps that I made from tutorials work perfectly fine, just the one that I recently created a layout for doesn't work.

Here is the Java code

```
package com.nubs.tableposv0_1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TablePOSv0_1Activity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Here is the updated XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <Button android:id="@+id/item1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Item 1"
            />
        <Button android:id="@+id/item2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Item 2"
            />
        <Button android:id="@+id/item3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Item 3"
            />
        <Button android:id="@+id/item4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Item 4"
            />
        <Button android:id="@+id/item5"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Item 5"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <Button android:id="@+id/item6"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Item 6"
            />
        <Button android:id="@+id/item7"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Item 7"
            />
        <Button android:id="@+id/item8"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Item 8"
            />
        <Button android:id="@+id/item9"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Item 9"
            />
        <Button android:id="@+id/item10"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Item 10"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="9"
        >
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/items_table"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            >
            </TableLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="3"
            >
            <Button android:id="@+id/calc1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="1"
                />
            <Button android:id="@+id/calc2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="2"
                />
            <Button android:id="@+id/calc3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="3"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="3"
            >
            <Button android:id="@+id/calc4"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="4"
                />
            <Button android:id="@+id/calc5"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="5"
                />
            <Button android:id="@+id/calc6"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="6"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="3"
            >
            <Button android:id="@+id/calc7"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="7"
                />
            <Button android:id="@+id/calc8"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="8"
                />
            <Button android:id="@+id/calc9"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="9"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="3"
            >
            <Button android:id="@+id/calc0"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="0"
                />
            <Button android:id="@+id/calcdec"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="."
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <Button android:id="@+id/total"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:text="Total"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
07-22 01:24:41.793: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(392):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
07-22 01:24:41.793: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(392):     at com.nubs.tableposv0_1.TablePOSv0_1Activity.onCreate(TablePOSv0_1Activity.java:15)
07-22 01:24:41.793: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(392):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-22 01:24:41.793: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(392):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-22 01:24:41.793: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(392):     ... 11 more
07-22 01:25:41.482: ERROR/DefContainer(224): Couldn't copy file: /data/local/tmp/TablePOSv0_1.apk
```

Comment: That's not a lot to go on. Try to isolate if it's your code or your dev tools.

Comment: I added the XML code for the layout. I haven't touched any of the JAVA code, but I added that too.

Comment: Why did you edited out the XML layout?!? Please, don't go changing your stuff like that... I was looking at it to see if I could spot something... and if that was the solution, it's advised to accept the answer by clicking in the green tick.

Comment: @David Because he's new on SO and somebody with 6k+ reputation ignorantly told him it was useless. And Jim, you were correct in assuming the XML was the problem, especially since you hadn't touched the Java, so it definitely is useful to have posted in this question.  In the future, what most of us want to see is Logcat output to begin with.  It will help you and others resolve a ton of bugs in your apps.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have fixed the problem. How exactly do I use Logcat to find the error. I'm really new to Eclipse, Android, and this site for that matter. Sorry for any inconveniences ahead of time.

Comment: Yes Glendon, I'm very new here, very young, and I see that happening all the time already. Actually, just minutes ago, I saw two downvotes on a very "good enough" question. And besides, a downvote is never a replacement for an educated and polite correction and explanation written as a comment. Thanks!

Comment: @Jim: in eclipse, go at Window->Show View->Logcat. When you run the code in debug mode/emulator, red lines will appear. Those are the ones you need to copy. And let me say that you really need to check some tutorials on the net before diving into Android. Start with the common Hello World examples, get yourself to know the tools... adb, eclipse etc.

Comment: I've done a few of the tutorials, but am still relatively new to this. Not new to programming, but specifically to Android.

Also, when I run the debug, a window pops up saying "Source not found"

Comment: It looks like adding the "height" and "width" to each object fixed the program crashing. Unfortunately that messed up my UI. Thanks for the help though and thank you for putting up with my amateur ways!

Comment: See my other comment in my answer about weight breaking layouts. Also, I don't know what you're trying to do, but I don't know why you're weighting all those widgets...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, LinearLayouts require both `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` dimensions.

In your XML, there are several without `android:layout_width`.

Also, next time post your Logcat output. They are much more useful than the code itself in those cases. That's why I'm only guessing here a problem that happened to me once.

// edit:

If it's still crashing, try to include both dimensions in *all* widgets. I don't remember exactly if it's just layouts of all widgets that require both dimensions. And puh-lease, give us the logcat. :-)

Comment: Yes, all widgets need the dimensions except in special cases (inside a `TableRow`).

Comment: Adding height and width to all widgets fixed the issue. Thank you all!

Comment: I noticed that you said that adding the two dimensions borked your layout. Truth is, I see you're trying to 'weight' your layouts. Try to use "wrap_content" instead of "fill_parent" on the dimensions you want to be weighted. For example, on that first row of buttons, you'd want the height dimension to be wrap_content, since you're trying to weight the vertical dimension in your outer LinearLayout. Some people also try "0" as dimensions when weighting them. Try to experiment and see which cases work better.